# SAS exclude variables from selection in dictionary columns

Tags: dictionary, macros, sas

I need to do a loop over a list of variables but excluding some of those.
I wanted to add a prefix to each variable except for those.

I wrote a macro:

```
%macro addprefijo(tabla);
proc contents data = labo2.&tabla.;
title 'before renaming'; run;

proc sql;
select nvar into :num_vars
from dictionary.tables
where libname='LABO2' and memname="&tabla";
%put 'num_vars' &num_vars;


select distinct(name) into :var1-:var%trim(%left(&num_vars))
from dictionary.columns
where libname='LABO2' and memname="&tabla" /*and name not in ('cid', 'COUNTY', 'ESTADO') */;
quit;



proc datasets library=LABO2;
modify &tabla;
rename
%do i=1 %to &num_vars.; 
&&var&i = &tabla._&&var&i.
%end;
;
quit;
run;

proc contents data=LABO2.&tabla.;
title' after renaming';
run;

%mend;

%addprefijo(A_CLI);
```

I tried what is commented but crashes and with out it adds the prefix to all the variables. Those 3 variables are not in all the tables.

How can I solve it?

Thanks

Comment: Try removing %put from that PROC SQL block and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

The following should work. Using `proc contents` `out =` rather than dictionary tables. Also using the sql `separated by` syntax to create a space separated list of variables rather than indervidual indexed variables.

```
%macro addprefijo(tabla);
    proc contents 
        data = labo2.&tabla. 
        out = _a_contents 
        noprint;
    run;
    proc sql noprint;
        select NAME 
        into :vars separated by " "
        from _a_contents
        where NAME not in ('cid', 'COUNTY', 'ESTADO');
    quit;
    proc datasets library = labo2;
        modify &tabla.;
        rename
            %do i = 1 %to %sysfunc(countw(&vars., %str( ))); 
                %let var = %scan(&vars., &i., %str( ));
                &var. = &tabla._&var.
            %end;;
    quit;
%mend;
%addprefijo(A_CLI);
```